# Blank php page over Apache

Tags: php, apache2

I have installed php 7.0 and the apache2 server on my machine and made sure that the apache server is running (when I go to localhost, it shows the index.html page). I created a testdirectory, set the right permissions for it and placed a sample hello.php file in there. All it contains is:

```
<?php echo "it's working fine"; ?>
```

When I go to localhost/testdirectory I can see my hello.php file in the index, but when I click on it, there is no output.

However, if I run the php file through cli, I get the output, so the php is working fine.

Please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you configure Apache to know about PHP? It does not happen automatically

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php